# DivX Plus Codec query

Tags: divx, xvid

I installed the Divx Plus Codec Pack and only selected the install of the Plus Codec.

Why when I go to the Control Panel or Codec Settings does it list Divx Pro Codec as being on trial for 15days?

I see no mention of the Plus Codec Pack anywhere except when I go to uninstall DivX then its listed as installed.

Also is Xvid a good alternative to DivX for playing avis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only concern is decoding (playback), I'd go the VLC route.  VLC has all of its codecs self-contained, so it doesn't litter your system with files and potential conflicts which codec packs often do.  Five years ago they were more of a necessity, but these days there are many players as well as transcoding apps that have all of the necessary codecs baked into the app.

Answer (score 1):

I use [K-Light](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) its Codec Pack that is designed as a user-friendly solution for playing all your movie files. With the K-Lite Codec Pack you should be able to play 99% of all the movies that you download from the internet

or
[VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Comment: Thanks djshortbus, VLC seems to be logical way to go instead of chasing codecs!

Comment: I guess that 1% K-lite doesnt play are mkvs

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either 
Media Player Classic (MPC), VLC Player or Zoom Player.

These are the **BEST** media players for video. Have been for years and will be for years.
It is true they have some codecs bundled with them but you should still use a codec pack.
These allow you to play practically every video and audio format out there using direct show. This means that every program you have installed that uses direct show will utilize all the codecs, splitters, filters and everything else in the codec pack.
The best codec pack is the [K-lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm) as djshortbus suggested.

With the install of the k-light Codec Pack it scans the registry and removes other codecs it finds as well as potential conflicts and with a modern day system, a codec pack does not really slow it down.

The best combination is Media Player Classic (MPC) with K-Lite Codec Pack Mega.

I would have put more links for the players but the spam prevention mechanism prevented me from posting more than 1 link. sorry.